# Both <a> and form <name=""> can't work together ? In html PHP

Tags: php, html, href

If I use this code only `<a href works >` but I Want  name="send" also work at a time(in isset($_POST['send']). but it's not working. so can I do for both cases?

I need to download and also send data to the database at the same time.

```html
<a href="./users/assets/upload/file/<?php echo $result['product_file']; ?>">
  <form method="POST" action=" ">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #8CC63F;">
      <div class="col-lg-12 dw_text text-center">
        <button type="submit" name="send" style="font-size: 30px;">FREE DOWNLOAD</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</a>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. and you have no action - you can use AJAX to do both or redirect on the server

Comment: Using AJAX can I submit a value to the database and at a time I can use <a href> ?????

Comment: You can send the url of the href to the server and on return submit the form or you can submit the form and click the link when it returns or you can submit the form and the server redirects to the new URL - many ways to skin a cat

Comment: can you show me a demo code because im confused about this.

Comment: ok i got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting the form you will need to correct your HTML. It looks like you are calling a `url` upon pressing the Free Download button.

To correct the HTML, you can either directly use link's `url` as the form's `action` (like this)

```
  <form method="POST" action="./users/assets/upload/file/<?php echo $result['product_file']; ?>">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #8CC63F;">
      <div class="col-lg-12 dw_text text-center">
        <button type="submit" name="send" style="font-size: 30px;">FREE DOWNLOAD</button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

or use jQuery (as you mentioned in your comments) to submit the form to the same `url`. See an example below,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: "./users/assets/upload/file/<?php echo $result['product_file']; ?>",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) { } 
});
```

To keep the `url` neat in the above `ajax` submit, you can keep `$result['product_file'];` as a hidden field in the HTML. So, when we press the Free Download button, `$(this).serialize()` will serialize that value too. So, the url's would just looks something similar to this,

`url: "./users/assets/upload/file",`

In the PHP backend, the retrieval of `product_file` needs to be slightly ammended to accommodate this new change.

Hope this helps

Thank you

Comment: but "send" name is not working in this procedure for <?php isset()